# Zimbra behind a Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, zimbra

I mention my network architecture.

My service provider has not made zone delegations to manage my DNS, and currently I only have one PTR record pointing to one of my servers which has a real IP on the Internet.
The PTR registry is www and is accessible from the internet as www.example.com

The IP that I have assigned to that registry is 200.x.x.x. where I have hosted an Apache Web server.

Within my LAN I have a Zimbra mail server, and I would like to be able to publish it in order to use the webmail from the outside.
Example: www.example.com/mail

How can I configure the Apache web server to do reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [other Serverfault "Apache ProxyPass" question](https://serverfault.com/a/53768/25361)

And on [apache mod_proxy manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#examples)

```
ProxyPass /mail http://zimbra/
ProxyPassReverse /mail http://zimbra/
```